# The knee gives a mechanical advantage point for the leg, would a "reverse knee lever" also work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical

As shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/XnYO4TnpTCo), the simulated knee cap creates a fulcrum that allows for a better mechanical advantage for the muscles to pull the leg.

So I was wondering if the **reverse** would also work, or if it wouldn't change much at all.

For example, in this illustration I made on paint, it is shown a mechanical lever **type 3** with **20 cm of length**, where the load is on a **20 cm** distance from the **fulcrum** and the effort is at **10 cm** distance from the **fulcrum** and the effort is being done by a rope pulled by a motor.

[image: Illustration of a reverse knee lever]
(I know the illustration part is drawn like it is counting 20cm from the effort point, but it is because I'm bad at drawing)

Accordingly to [this online mechanical lever calculator](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/calculator/lever-mechanical-advantage/), inputing these numbers would give me 0.5 of mechanical advantage, so in order to lift 1 kg, I would need to input twice the value in order to achieve equilibrium.

However, if I insert a "reverse knee cap" over the effort at the same 10 cm distance and attached the effort rope directly to the point of the load arm, as shown in the illustration, would the mechanical advantage stay the same, or it would change?

Comment: So done any research to see if that concept has been applied in nature?

Comment: @SolarMike I tried and I couldn't find anything. Maybe I didn't use the right words...

Comment: Then consider what other words you could use.

Comment: A Google search (fantastic tool) gives https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-3190/abf744

Comment: Wildebeest or Boston Dynamics Spot.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Boston Dynamics have some good kit :)

Comment: `simulated knee cap creates a fulcrum` ... don't you mean `creates a lever`?

Comment: in the first diagram, what is the "knee" connected to?

Comment: @jsotola nothing, but it could be connected to either lever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tested it on the program "Interactive Physics", and it seems like it doesn't make much difference.

I don't know how to explain it very well, but the pulley that acts as the "inverse knee cap" applies force the same way if the effort arm was directly connected to the 10cm distance.

[image: Screenshot of the Interactive Physics program showing the results]

For example, i imitated the kneecap joint in this attempt at equal distances of 20 cm from the fulcrum and it kept everything under equilibrium:

[image: Screenshot of the interactive physics program]

Even if I try to make the pulley to be really close to the load:

[image: Screenshot of interactive physics]

Comment: Could you provide a link to the program you used?

Comment: https://www.physicscurriculum.com/interactivephysics

It is a paid program, but you can search for other options on youtube. @EricS

Comment: Thanks. I found this site which is both free and looks good. https://physion.net